# evaluate $\int \frac{\tan x}{x^2+1}\:dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{\tan x}{x^2+1}\,  \mathrm dx$$

I used By-parts method setting $u=\tan x$ and $\,  \mathrm dv=\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,  \mathrm dx$, but then I got an integral that's more complicated

I also thought of trigonometric substitution, setting $x=\tan\theta$, but how am going to substitute that for the $\tan x$ in numerator?

I tried to use websites like [symbolab](http://symbolab.com) & [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to evaluate the integral but I got no result.

Comment: I am going to guess that if this is coming from a homework, the intended question was $\int \text{arctan}(x)/(x^2+1)dx$ which has a nice form.

Comment: They probably meant $\tan^{-1}x=\arctan x$.

Comment: @EricNaslund No, it's not, if it were arctanx instead of tanx, I would not ask such a question :). then it's going to be very easy.

Answer (score 5):

The Laurent series of tan(x) is
$$\sum_{n=1,3,5..}^{\infty }\frac{8x}{(n\pi )^2-4x^2}$$
so
$$\frac{\tan(x)}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=1,3,5..}^{\infty }\frac{8x}{\left [(n\pi )^2-4x^2  \right ](1+x^2)}$$

use the partial fraction to get
$$\sum_{n=1,3,5,..}^{\infty }\frac{8x}{((n\pi)^2+4 )(1+x^2)}+\frac{8}{((n\pi)^2+4 )(n\pi -2x)}-\frac{8}{((n\pi)^2+4 )(n\pi +2x)}$$

$$\int \frac{\tan x}{1+x^2}dx=C+\sum_{n=1,3,5,..}^{\infty }\frac{4}{(n\pi )^2+4}\left [ \log(1+x^2)-\log(n\pi -2x)-\log(n\pi +2x) \right ]$$

hence

$$\int \frac{\tan x}{1+x^2}dx=C+\sum_{n=1,3,5,..}^{\infty }\frac{4}{(n\pi )^2+4}\left [ \log(\frac{1+x^2}{(n\pi )^2-4x^2}) \right ]$$

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Hope it helps. It also turns into a more complicated as I thought. You might use Matlab to calculate this.

Comment: where'd you get that?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: So a picture is not accepted here?

Comment: Many would accept but some serious users will not. Better take no risk.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, and how can I get more help with my questions..?

Comment: I'm going to up you because I see nothing wrong with pictures.

Comment: @randomgirl she is one of the "caring" ones. (^_^)

Comment: @randomgirl  Thank you!!

Comment: Pls help me with this question...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233220/find-the-expected-value-exk?noredirect=1#comment2507681_1233220

Comment: @Kevin217 w8 and you will surely get some good answers, maybe users with knowledge of the topic are not on9 wait 1-2 days.

Comment: @ADG lol that's great. I regret I haven't find this website earlier.