# Indefinite integral of $\frac{\tan{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let $f(x) = \frac{\tan{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}$ , find $\int f(x)dx$ . I've tried many substitutions (including trigonometric substitutions like $x=\tan \theta$ ) and also integration by parts but didn't work . We can apply power series but it doesn't solve problem .

Comment: I am afraid that, even using special functions, closed form solutions could be difficult to get.

Comment: Hmm.. this guy is fighting back pretty hard..

Comment: Where did you find this beast?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan My friend asked that beast!

Comment: Does your friend know the answer?

Comment: Integration by parts in such cases generally results in asymptotic expansion

Comment: I think there is know elementary solution known.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233230/evaluate-int-frac-tan-xx21-dx?rq=1 this should help but replace tan(X) for tan(x^2+1)

Comment: Are you sure that he/she is a friend ?

Comment: @ricky. There will be a problem since even $\int \tan(1+x^2)\,dx$ is not known.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici can he use The Laurent series of tan(x) like in the link but for every x in the expansion replace that for (x^2+1), then go on to split it into partial fractions etc or am I just being stupid haha?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes ! I think he made that himself.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you explain your idea ?

Comment: It is really interesting, for substituting $x=\tan t$ gives $I= \int \tan \sec^2t dt$

Comment: I feel that it can have a good series form solution.

Comment: What I wrote can be significantly improved using the $[6,2]$  Padé approximant for $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem was
$$\int_0^a \frac{\tan{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}\,dx \qquad \text{with} \qquad 0 \leq a \lt \sqrt{\frac{\pi -2}{2}}\approx 0.7555$$ it could be possible to have an *approximation* of it using a Padé approximant built at $x=0$.

Using $k=\tan(1)$, we should have
$$ \frac{\tan{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}=\frac {3 k \left(-2 k^2+2 k+1\right)+3 \left(-k^2+k+1\right)x^2 +(2 k-3) \left(k^2+1\right)x^4} {3(-2 k^2+2 k+1)+ 6 (k-1)^2 k x^2+(6 k^3-7 k^2-4)x^4}$$ which can be integrated using partial fraction decomposition (leading to a nasty expression. Numerically, this would be "almost" (making the coefficient rational)
$$\int \frac{\tan{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}\,dx \simeq \frac{184 }{789}x+\frac{1099} {3526}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{529
   }{801}x\right)+\frac{1409 }{1667}\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{692
   }{523}x\right)$$ For a few values of $a$, some results (the so called "exact" being obtained by numerical integration)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.05 & 0.07795 & 0.07795 \\
 0.10 & 0.15637 & 0.15637 \\
 0.15 & 0.23577 & 0.23577 \\
 0.20 & 0.31670 & 0.31670 \\
 0.25 & 0.39982 & 0.39982 \\
 0.30 & 0.48593 & 0.48593 \\
 0.35 & 0.57609 & 0.57610 \\
 0.40 & 0.67171 & 0.67172 \\
 0.45 & 0.77482 & 0.77482 \\
 0.50 & 0.88848 & 0.88848 \\
 0.55 & 1.01775 & 1.01775 \\
 0.60 & 1.17192 & 1.17195 \\
 0.65 & 1.37127 & 1.37136 \\
 0.70 & 1.67673 & 1.67722 \\
 0.75 & 2.66909 & 2.68502
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We can make the approximation better using the fact that
$$f(x)=\left(x^2-\frac{\pi }{2}+1\right)\frac{ \tan \left(x^2+1\right)}{x^2+1}$$ is a quite nice function. Using a $[4,2]$ Padé approximant, we get
$$f(x) \simeq\frac {a_0+a_1 x^2+a_2 x^4 }{b_0+b_1 x^2 }$$ where
$$a_0=3 (\pi -2) k \left(\pi  (k ((k-1) k+2)-1)-2 \left(k^3+k\right)\right)$$
$$a_1=6 \pi -\left(k^2+1\right) \left(3 (\pi -2) \pi  k^2+((8-5 \pi ) \pi -8) k+3 \pi ^2\right)$$
$$a_2=\left(k^2+1\right) \left(2 (\pi -2) (1+\pi ) k^2-2 \pi  (1+\pi ) k-(\pi -10) \pi   -4\right)$$
$$b_0=6 (k (k (\pi -(\pi -2) k)-2 \pi +2)+\pi )$$
$$b_1=2 \left(k \left(k \left(3 (\pi -2) k^2-3 \pi  k+7 \pi -8\right)-6 \pi \right)+4 \pi   -2\right)$$ leading to
$$\int \frac{\tan{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}\,dx \simeq \frac{a_2 }{b_1}x-\frac{2 \left(b_1 (a_0 b_1-a_1 b_0)+a_2
   b_0^2\right)}{\sqrt{b_0} b_1^{3/2} (2 b_0+(\pi -2) b_1)}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{b_1} }{\sqrt{b_0}}x\right) -\frac{(4 a_0+(\pi -2) (2 a_1+(\pi -2)
   a_2))}{\sqrt{2 (\pi -2)} (2 b_0+(\pi -2) b_1)}\tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi -2}} x\right) $$ Making the same table as before
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.05 & 0.07795 & 0.07795 \\
 0.10 & 0.15637 & 0.15637 \\
 0.15 & 0.23577 & 0.23577 \\
 0.20 & 0.31670 & 0.31670 \\
 0.25 & 0.39982 & 0.39982 \\
 0.30 & 0.48593 & 0.48593 \\
 0.35 & 0.57610 & 0.57610 \\
 0.40 & 0.67172 & 0.67172 \\
 0.45 & 0.77482 & 0.77482 \\
 0.50 & 0.88848 & 0.88848 \\
 0.55 & 1.01776 & 1.01775 \\
 0.60 & 1.17197 & 1.17195 \\
 0.65 & 1.37142 & 1.37136 \\
 0.70 & 1.67740 & 1.67722 \\
 0.75 & 2.68589 & 2.68502
\end{array}
\right)$$ which looks quite better.

Comment: Thanks , I keep this question open for more answers .

Comment: @S.H.W : For sure, keep it open. It is very interesting. I am still working on it. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, I think my Maxima  made an error , soon I shall post a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Mittag-Leffler Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem#Pole_expansions_of_meromorphic_functions) of [tangent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388398),

$\int\dfrac{\tan{(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}~dx=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{8}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2-4(x^2+1)^2}~dx$